# Better way to indent function entries

Tags: php, nested, auto-indent, dtrace

I've the following dtrace script:

```
#!/usr/sbin/dtrace -Zs
#pragma D option quiet
php*:::function-entry {
    printf("%Y: PHP function-entry :%*s%s %s%s%s() in %s:%d\n", walltimestamp, ++indent, "", "->", copyinstr(arg3), copyinstr(arg4), copyinstr(arg0), basename(copyinstr(arg1)), (int)arg2);
}

php*:::function-return {
    printf("%Y: PHP function-return:%*s%s %s%s%s() in %s:%d\n", walltimestamp, indent--, "", "<-", copyinstr(arg3), copyinstr(arg4), copyinstr(arg0), basename(copyinstr(arg1)), (int)arg2);
}
```

which seems to work for simple PHP code such as:

```
<?php
function a() { b(); }
function b() { c(); }
function c() { d(); }
function d() { e(); }
function e() { }
a();
```

for example:

```
$ sudo ./trace-php.d 
2016 Apr  9 01:41:29: PHP function-entry : -> a() in foo.php:2
2016 Apr  9 01:41:29: PHP function-entry :  -> b() in foo.php:3
2016 Apr  9 01:41:29: PHP function-entry :   -> c() in foo.php:4
2016 Apr  9 01:41:29: PHP function-entry :    -> d() in foo.php:5
2016 Apr  9 01:41:29: PHP function-entry :     -> e() in foo.php:6
2016 Apr  9 01:41:29: PHP function-return:     <- e() in foo.php:6
2016 Apr  9 01:41:29: PHP function-return:    <- d() in foo.php:5
2016 Apr  9 01:41:29: PHP function-return:   <- c() in foo.php:4
2016 Apr  9 01:41:29: PHP function-return:  <- b() in foo.php:3
2016 Apr  9 01:41:29: PHP function-return: <- a() in foo.php:2
```

However when I'm testing it with more complex scripts, e.g. running `drush status`, `php index.php` (on Drupal site), or using builtin PHP server, it goes off the screen to the next line, and another one and doesn't come back to the same place, so after few minutes I've few hundreds (even thousands) of space characters. And it's not possible that the code is going so deep, since I've `xdebug.max_nesting_level=256` which prevents too deep recursion.

What causing the above logic to fail and how it can be improved?

Comment: The D tag prolly isn't going to help much, it is watched by the dlang.org D programming language folks rather than the dtrace users. I'm one of the other D users, i don't know dtrace, but, what I'd do here is run the output through a helper program that crushes space. Something like piping it through sed and `s/                /:/g` to turn huge series of spaces into something a little more readable. (edit: ugh the display of the code is broken, that is supposed to be like 16 spaces, not one.)

Comment: @AdamD.Ruppe Thanks, I wasn't sure. On wiki it was written that dtrace scripts are in D language, so I thought it's relevant. Thanks for clarifying.